# "Crosstab" query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, crosstab

Using SQL Server 2008, looking to query one table but looking for specific output.  Current table, named fmCalendar:

```
>Date       Calendar    Days
>12/30/2014 Canada      1
>12/30/2014 Europe      1
>12/30/2014 UK          1
>12/30/2014 US          1
>12/29/2014 Canada      2
>12/29/2014 Europe      2
>12/29/2014 UK          3
>12/29/2014 US          3
>...
```

I'd like the output to look like this:

```
>Date       Canada  Europe  UK  US
>12/30/2014 1       1       1   1
>12/29/2014 2       2       3   3
>...
```

How do I do this?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would query it like

```
select
  Date,
  Sum(case when Calendar = 'Canada' then Days else 0 end) as Canada,
  Sum(case when Calendar = 'Europe' then Days else 0 end) as Europe,
  Sum(case when Calendar = 'UK' then Days else 0 end) as UK,
  Sum(case when Calendar = 'US' then Days else 0 end) as Us,
  Sum(case when Calendar not in ('Canada','Europe','UK','US') then Days else 0 end) 
  as Other
from
  MyTable
group by
   Date
```

Comment: That would seem to work but I am getting an invalid column name for all four regions

Comment: I figured it out - double quotes vs single quotes - fixed - thanks!

Comment: Fixed quotes and formatting. If it work for you, please select as solution

Comment: how do I "select as solution"?

Comment: @mdecav When an answer is the one that helped you the most, or the one that you used, you can accept it as the correct answer. You should see a checkmark in every answer, clicking that makes it the accepted answer. ([accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer))

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM fmCalendar AS T
PIVOT(SUM([days]) FOR Calendar IN ([Canada],[Europe],[UK],[US])) AS P
```

[**Here is an sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f96f0/1) with a demo. The results are:

```
╔═══════════════════╦════════╦════════╦════╦════╗
║       DATE        ║ CANADA ║ EUROPE ║ UK ║ US ║
╠═══════════════════╬════════╬════════╬════╬════╣
║ December, 29 2014 ║      2 ║      2 ║  3 ║  3 ║
║ December, 30 2014 ║      1 ║      1 ║  1 ║  1 ║
╚═══════════════════╩════════╩════════╩════╩════╝
```

Comment: That would seem to be a simpler (and easier) solution, but I am getting a syntax error near 'PIVOT'.  Not sure why.

Comment: @mdecav Well, that **is** weird since this same query is used in the sqlfiddle and it doesn't throw an error. Are you sure that you are using the exact same query?

Comment: Yes; I have no idea why.  Never used PIVOT before.

Comment: @mdecav The database (or server) that you are querying may not be SQL Server 2008, but 2000 instead